# undefined reference to `memcached_exist'

Tags: c, memcached, exists

I Am using C NOT C++

I am trying to use the memcached_exist in C but I get this error:

```
undefined reference to `memcached_exist'
```

here's my code:

```
  #include <stdio.h>
  #include <string.h>
  #include <unistd.h>
  #include <libmemcached/memcached.h>


  int main(int argc, char *argv[])  {

   memcached_server_st *servers = NULL;
    memcached_st *memc;
    memcached_return rc;
    char *key= "keystring";
    char *value= "keyvalue";

  //  memcached_server_st *memcached_servers_pars (char *server_strings);
    memc= memcached_create(NULL);

    servers= memcached_server_list_append(servers, "localhost", 11211, &rc);
    rc= memcached_server_push(memc, servers);
rc= memcached_set(memc, key, strlen(key), value, strlen(value), expire, flag);                                                                           
  rc = memcached_exist(memc, key, strlen(key));
```

I am compiling with: -lmemcached -lmemcachedutil

This solution does not work since I am using C:

[ibmemcached Linking Error: undefined reference to `memcached_exist'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16679178/ibmemcached-linking-error-undefined-reference-to-memcached-exist)

Comment: Read the last two code snippets in your question very carefully and look at cyan highlighted text.

Comment: @Olaf im sorry im colorblind ... what highlighted text?

Comment: @Olaf anyway my point is why I get an "undefined reference" ... the file is there in /usr/include/libmemcached-1.0/

Comment: I know it's not what you asked, but is your defined function `memcached_exist()` intended to recurse infinitely (until the stack breaks)? Back on topic, please provide a complete example that won't compile only because of the one problem.

Comment: @WeatherVane Updated question

Comment: Your edit changed the meaning of your question completely.

Comment: possible duplicate of [ibmemcached Linking Error: undefined reference to \`memcached\_exist'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16679178/ibmemcached-linking-error-undefined-reference-to-memcached-exist)

Comment: @undefinedbehaviour Not applicable .. I am using C NOT C++

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that in order to provide a short and concise answer, I'd need an [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), including **the complete command you're using to compile** since this requires some extra switches beyond basic compilation. However, there is a conclusive answer to this question... which *you've given us*, by the way, but we'll get to that later. First, let's cover the more common causes.

This is a linker error. Linker errors usually fall into one of three categories:

- A library was missing in the compilation/linking phase. [The documentation](http://docs.libmemcached.org/libmemcached/memcached_exist.html) indicates that you've linked to the correct library.
- **Linking order!** The placement of `-lmemcached -lmemcachedutil` is significant, in this case. If your command is along the lines of `cc -lmemcached file.c`, this is your (at least part of) error. It needs to look more like: `cc file.c -lmemcached`...
- A typographic error. Based on [the documentation](http://docs.libmemcached.org/libmemcached/memcached_exist.html) and in spite of the question you linked to, it would initially seem like this isn't your case. However, if you inspect the question you linked to more closely then you'll notice that *that wasn't using C++, either*! Perhaps your question *is* a duplicate of that question, with the exception of course that you haven't given *anywhere near as much information* as that question. A quick search for [the source code](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~tangent-trunk/libmemcached/1.0/files/head:/libmemcached/) indicates that [this function (memcached_exist)](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~tangent-trunk/libmemcached/1.0/view/head:/libmemcached/exist.cc#L125) is compiled from a file named *exist.cc*, using... you guessed it: A C++ compiler. So considering the name mangling that *will* occur (especially because the actual function isn't defined using `extern "C"`), you've got a typographic error, whether you're willing to accept it or not. Have you observed the presense (or lack) of name mangling, using the command that's in the question you linked to (`nm libmemcached.so | grep -i memcached_exist`)? If you can see the name mangling, perhaps you should [try the answer to the question you linked to, anyway](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16680834/1989425)...

Comment: the incorrect library was not good, I got the 1.0.18 and it worked thanks